# How to read the ul id?

Tags: jquery

I am having `<ul class= "list" id = "List">`

I want to read the ul id

`$("li:last-child input:button").live('click', function () {
             var val = $(this).closest('ul').val();
             alert(val);
         });`

How can I do that? In the above the alert is not displaying the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val()` returns an input's value. You want the ID attribute:

```
$("li:last-child input:button").live("click", function() {
  var id = $(this).closest("ul").attr("id");
  alert(id);
});
```

You can use `attr()` on a jQuery object or `id` on a DOM element object to get the ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
  $("li:last-child input:button").live('click', function () { 
        var val =  $(this).closest('ul').attr('id'); 
        alert(val); 
  });
```